# How to Upgrade from 11.10 to 12.04 when you've got a problem?

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, updates, ram

I have recently installed 8GB Ram into my ubuntu machine but when I look on the specs it only comes up with 2.8GB of Ram so I want to upgrade to 12.04 but when I try to upgrade it says it can't because it cant find the archive to update a program first and when it tries to delete or update the program it dosent work. So how do I upgrade to 12.04 with these problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you aren't using a PAE kernel and your 11.10 is 32-bit.  Is this right?  In order to address all 8GB of RAM you should consider starting over with a 64-bit operating system.

As for the upgrade, you should disable all 3rd party sources, then try to update your system.  Then upgrade.

Comment: your right about the 32bit and how do you disable 3rd party sources?

Comment: Open up the Ubuntu Software Center, then find the menu entry for 'software sources'.  Here you will see a list of the repositories configured for your machine.  Uncheck the ones that you remember adding manually and click close.  Then do sudo apt-get update, sudo apt-get upgrade, then upgrade to 12.04.

Answer (score 2):

To use full RAM you need to enable PAE.

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-pae linux-headers-generic-pae
```

For Upgrade

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'll give you an upvote just for all the screenshots. Where did you find a computer that just happened to be missing these packages, so you could go through the installation and take all these? =)

Comment: This not the missing package image. This image show how to upgrade to 12.04. Please check 1st before judge. :)

Comment: Well, you had a computer at hand which you could upgrade and take screenshots. Dedication deserves reputation!

Answer (score 0):

Addressing the first part of your question, 32-bit operating systems, whether Windows or Ubuntu, will not recognize all of your new memory.  To recognize all of your memory you will need to install a 64-bit operating system.  The simplest way would be to download the 64-bit (not the recommended version) of Ubuntu and install it.

Remember to backup any important files before you do this.  I just did the install and I thought by default it would ask me where to install it.  It didn't.  Know I have to figure out if it installed in the correct place and redo the install if it didn't.  I have several operating systems on my computer and wanted the latest version of Ubuntu to be install on my new Solid State Drive (SSD).

Comment: Or, to recognize all the memory, one can **run a PAE kernel on a 32-bit operating system**, which Ubuntu fully supports. In Ubuntu 12.04, the PAE kernel is the only packaged 32-bit kernel.